# Difference between 1 language vs 2 languages for Mobile APP

Tags: c#, java, android, iphone, objective-c

For mobile apps, I know that they can be written in Java for Android and in Objective C for iPhone. Someone briefly mentioned to me that it is actually better to use one universal language for the app across different phones with the language C#. He implied that one language is always better for an application on both Android and iPhone, but I know this sounds too good to be true.

What is the difference between using 2 different languages (java / objective c) for an application on two different types of phone versus one language (c#) for the application that works on both phones?

What are the pros and cons of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each platform has their *official* language and SDK to develop native applications. It is the supported language and SDK, so if you use this native language you will get all features, will be up-to-date and your application will run fastest (unless you wrote crap code, but that's something developers never do, so we can safely exclude this hypothesis).

There are some frameworks (such as [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)) which allow you to write applications with the same language and run it on multiple platforms. The pros is obvious => same code that runs everywhere. The cons is that those frameworks usually don't support some of the unique features of the specific platform because those features don't exist on other platforms. Also since there's an automated translation between C# and the target native language of the platform, during this translation there might be some issues.

Comment: Are there any other pros for 1 language other than it being the same code that runs everywhere? Is there a possibility one language could have certain advantages or be faster at times? I do recall this peer mentioning that dealing with data is actually more efficient in 1 language.

Comment: At the contrary, if you are looking for speed, performance and fluidity you should use the native language of the specific platform, not an universal language.

Comment: Let us assume that I have all the resources and time necessary for both options. Is writing the application in each respected native language always the best option?

Comment: If you have the resources, then yes, writing the application in the native language is the best option. But obviously having those resources is the problem, because in the real world you seldom have them, and that's why universal frameworks exist in order to cut development costs :-)

Comment: Just taking my first step into the mobile app world, I've been also wondering if everything implemented in Objective C can also be implemented in Java (and vice versa). I would imagine that each different native language would have a different set of features, so my question is can the app be exactly the same while being written in two different languages? "Exactly" might be too strong of a word, but I mean for an application purpose, can everything be the same, like the implementation of functions, methods, UI, etc. Or are there certain limitations one language can do but another can't?

Comment: Each language has its specific features. So it is not true, in the general case, that everything you implement with one language, you will be able to implement with another. But for application purpose, I guess that you will be able to achieve pretty close functions no matter the language. Of course that's subjective and will depend on the situation, if you want more precise answer you will have to ask a specific question.